# Eventbrite find user id when given Organisation name or email address

Tags: eventbrite

I'm building a system where a user can log in to my website and manage events via the Eventbrite api, the only unique identifier every account will have on creation is a user id, is there a way to have a user input their username, query the api and return their user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventbrite are working on integrating the organiser_id into the API, this will allow you to do a similar thing when it is live